# Function's __annotations__ attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, annotations, type-hinting

There is a paragraph in [`__annotations__` Quirks](https://docs.python.org/3.10/howto/annotations.html#annotations-quirks) which says:

> In all versions of Python 3, function objects lazy-create an annotations dict if no annotations are defined on that object. You can delete the `__annotations__` attribute using `del fn.__annotations__`, but if you then access `fn.__annotations__` the object will create a new empty dict that it will store and return as its annotations. **Deleting the annotations on a function before it has lazily created its annotations dict will throw an `AttributeError`; using `del fn.__annotations__` twice in a row is guaranteed to always throw an `AttributeError`**.

I don't quite understand the last sentence. I'm not able to raise `AttributeError` in any way.

If you ask me why do I need this, I don't. I'm just asking because after reading that paragraph I couldn't reproduce that exception.

```py
>>> def fn1(a, b):
...     return a + b
... 
>>> del fn1.__annotations__
>>> del fn1.__annotations__
>>> del fn1.__annotations__
>>> 
>>> def fn2(a: str, b: int) -> str:
...     return a * b
... 
>>> del fn2.__annotations__
>>> del fn2.__annotations__
>>> del fn2.__annotations__
```

Tested on Python 3.10.6

Comment: I was not able to raise this error on Python 3.11.3 either.

Comment: Not raised on python 3.9.16 and 3.8.16 as well. Please consider reporting this to python issues (https://github.com/python/cpython/issues).

Comment: reported. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/106868